# Script will not run in SciLab 6.0.0

Tags: scilab

The script below runs fine in SciLab 5.5.2. In 6.0.0 it crashes when the `csim()` function is executed (line 21).

For this test set x0 = [1 1.5 .25 .125];

The error reads as;

```
 lsode--  caution... t (=r1) and h (=r2) are
     such that t + h = t at next step
      (h = step).  integration continues
      where r1 is :   0.0000000000000D+00   and r2 :   0.0000000000000D+00      
lsode--  at t (=r1) with step h (=r2), 
     corrector does not converge 
      with abs(h) = hmin   
      where r1 is :   0.0000000000000D+00   and r2 :   0.0000000000000D+00      
Repeated convergence failures (perhaps bad jacobian supplied or wrong choice of jacobian type or tolerances).
at line     6 of function optimbase_checkstatus  ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.0\modules\optimization\macros\optimbase\optimbase_checkcostfun.sci line 121 )
at line    14 of function optimbase_checkcostfun ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.0\modules\optimization\macros\optimbase\optimbase_checkcostfun.sci line 33 )
at line     7 of function neldermead_startup     ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.0\modules\optimization\macros\neldermead\neldermead_search.sci line 951 )
at line    23 of function neldermead_search      ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.0\modules\optimization\macros\neldermead\neldermead_search.sci line 65 )
at line   129 of executed file C:\Users\wensrl\Documents\SciLab\Reference Documentation\pidOptimizer.sce
```

optimbase_checkcostfun: Cannot evaluate cost function with "[f,index]=costf(x0,1)": ode: lsode exit with state -5.

This errors occurs when the csim function is executed.

I searched for changes to the `csim()` function between versions 5.5.2 and 6.0.0 and did not find any. Is there a solution that I am missing here?

function [J, index] = costf(x0, index)

```
global J C oL cL itae OS Ms y u t wgts iteration cost

[lhs, rhs] = argn(0)
if rhs < 1 then
    error("x0 is required")
end

kc    = x0(1);
ti    = x0(2);
td    = x0(3);
alpha = x0(4);

// stdDeltaV PID formula
pidFormula = kc * (1 + (1/(ti * %s)) + ...
             ((td * %s)/(alpha * td * %s + 1)))

// pidFormula = pidCTRL(1, pidParam)

C = syslin('c', pidFormula)

oL = Pd * C
cL = oL /. 1

[y] = csim(u', t, cL)

for i = 1:totalTelements
    e(i) = abs(y(i) - u(i)) * dt
end

itae         = sum(e)
OS           = max(y) - 1
[Se, Re, Te] = sensi(Pd, C);
Ms           = norm (Se, %inf);

J = wgts(1) * itae  +  wgts(2) * OS  +  wgts(3) * Ms;
```

endfunction

Comment: Could you improve your question to provide an example of when it crashes? What should the inputs ``x0`` and ``index`` be? What output should be expected and what is the error message that Scilab returns?

Comment: For this snip-it x0 = [ 1.4 2.3 0.2 0.125] and index = 1

The error message received is in the next couple of comments;
 at line     6 of function optimbase_checkstatus  ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.0\modules\optimization\macros\optimbase\optimbase_checkcostfun.sci line 121 )
at line    14 of function optimbase_checkcostfun ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.0\modules\optimization\macros\optimbase\optimbase_checkcostfun.sci line 33 )
at line     7 of function neldermead_startup     ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.0\modules\optimization\macros\neldermead\neldermead_search.sci line 951 )

Comment: at line    23 of function neldermead_search      ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.0\modules\optimization\macros\neldermead\neldermead_search.sci line 65 )
at line   113 of executed file C:\Users\wensrl\Documents\SciLab\Reference Documentation\pidOptimizer.sce

optimbase_checkcostfun: Cannot evaluate cost function with "[f,index]=costf(x0,1)": contr: Wrong type for input argument #2: A real matrix expected.

Comment: You should edit the question, actually. So that everyone can see the error.

Comment: Original question has been edited.  Thank you for the advice.

Comment: First, Pd is not defined. If I set it to 1, then I get the error: `csim: Incompatible input arguments #1 and #2: Same column dimensions expected.`

Comment: Pd is solved before the function is called and is a global variable.
it is defined as 
P  = syslin('c', kp, 1 + tau * %s)
n = 4 // order of the delay function
delay = 1 / (( 1 + ((%s * theta) / n)) ^n) // made into a function
Pd = P * delay
where;
kp = 0.8
delay = 3
theta = 11